# When running local script on remote server via multiple ssh, script is split into multiple lines?

Tags: shell-script, ssh

I have a script on my local machine, `script.sh`. I want to run it on a remote server that is only accessible by multiple ssh.

script.sh:

```
ls
ls
ls
```

I tried:

```
user@localhost:~/$ ssh -At host1 ssh -At host2 "bash -s" -- < ./script.sh
```

but the output was split onto multiple lines:

```
user@host2:~/$ ls
examples.desktop
user@host2:~/$ ls
examples.desktop
user@host2:~/$ ls
```

I also would like this to execute without putting me in a terminal on the remote machine.

How can I get the script to execute as a single command?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by removing the `-t` flag, so that ssh didn't put me in a terminal on the remote host.

```
user@localhost:~/$ ssh -A host1 ssh -A host2 "bash -s" -- < ./script.sh
```

Output:

```
examples.desktop
examples.desktop
examples.desktop
user@localhost:~/$
```

It also kept me on the local host rather than landing me in a terminal on the remote host.